# Google SpreadSheet saving "undefined" values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

My case is this, I'm Trying to save data or values taken from a form created on GUI Builder, the first time I've used the example script posted on  [link to google script documentation ][1]

It worked good, I was able to take values typed at the form, but when I decided to use the GUI Builder because, we need more text fields and stuff, It stop working, Every time that I click the button, my spreadsheet gets an "Undefined" value.

I've checked all the IDs and all of them are exactly as the script.

The code:

_guardar : This function inserts textfield values to the spreadsheet.
celda means cell in english
ultimaFila means lastRow

```
   function doGet(e) {      
   var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Au-gVDPWE5-bdDhJQzc2N2U4Q2l3LVY2cWpkbHdXMVE'); 
   var app = UiApp.createApplication();      
   app.add(app.loadComponent("MyForm"));
   return app;
 }  


function _guardar(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Au-gVDPWE5-bdDhJQzc2N2U4Q2l3LVY2cWpkbHdXMVE');
  var ultimaFila = doc.getLastRow(); 
  var celda = doc.getRange('a1').offset(ultimaFila, 0); 
  celda.setValue(e.parameter.nombre);
  celda.offset(0, 1).setValue(e.parameter.empresa); 
  celda.offset(0, 2).setValue(e.parameter.nit); 
  celda.offset(0, 3).setValue(e.parameter.sector); 
  celda.offset(0, 4).setValue(e.parameter.telefono); 
  celda.offset(0, 5).setValue(e.parameter.email); 
  celda.offset(0, 6).setValue(e.parameter.web); 
  celda.offset(0, 7).setValue(e.parameter.descripcion);      


  app.close();

  return app; 

}
```

This is similar to the example code at the google documentation site.![enter image description here][2]

Also I've checked that the "OnClick" event ,is it set on "_enviar" function.

All the textboxs and labels are contained in a Absolute panel, including the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the IDs that have to correspond to the parameter but the names.
These are defined in another tab in the GUI builder and are used to get the values  with e.parameter.name

see screen capture below :

[image]

EDIT : following your comment, did you check the callback element in the GUI ? is it the parent panel ?

[image]

Comment: I already check that , but those are ok, the ID and the Name atribute are the same. like in your picture. :( 

Thank you.

Comment: See the Main code at the upper side of the post. Do I Have to add something there?

Comment: It would be easier to add in the GUI builder itself as shown in my edit.  You can add the 'mother' panel or every element separated with commas... your choice.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get it, when I put 'MainPanel' (I've renamed the AboslutePanel that contains the whole form labels, textboxs, buttons etc.) and then refresh the site, and press the button, a pop up windows shows "Error encountered:Unknow macro 'MainPanel'"

Comment: Forgot to tell you I'm implementing as a "web app"

Comment: I'll figure it out, I was Using a Submit button, I've deleted and created a normal button and also, added again the callback element that you mentioned, in this case was named "MainPanel". Thank You for your time patience.

Comment: Glad it helped, the GUI builder is always quite tricky to debug on this ( forum without pictures :-) (sorry for the delay,I'm in GMT+2 :-)

Comment: Don't worry about the delay, I wasn't able to put images 'cause I don't have enough "Reputation" :-/